# Multi-tenant architecture - SQL views vs application logic, or both?

Tags: saas, multi-tenant

Firstly, let me start by saying that I haven't ever directly used SQL views. I don't know if they are an antiquated thing, or if they're the right way to do things in this arena. Which of the 2 methods do you prefer when considering security (don't show Acme's credit card number that's on file to a WidgetCorp user, etc), and are there other important considerations besides security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use it for

1. Security purposes like you described
2. In sub queries. Helps to keep my queries more compact, efficient with indexed views and also if I find myself reusing the same sub-query them I just make it into a view.

Here something to [read.](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Views_-_Advantages_and_Disadvantages)